# iPhone Message button from a picture in an app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I would like to implement a feature on my app that when a picture is clicked that it opens up a dialog similar to the dialog opened when you are on a specific picture and you click the icon at the bottom left of the screen. When that is clicked it gives you 7 buttons (Email Photo, Message, Assign to Contact, Use as Wallpaper, Tweet, Print, and Cancel). Would it be possible to do something similar in an app I am developing?

I really would only want the functionality to message and email but mostly just messaging.

thanks

Comment: I do not think there is an automatic way to to this, if that is what you mean.  There is no "send this information out anyway you can" API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a [`UIActionSheet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  To make the picture tap sensitive, you can attach a [`UIGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to it.

Comment: Thank you I will have a go at this tomorrow evening.